# MacBook Pro 2020 Model - External Monitors Now Have Strange White, semi-transparent, Box On Top Left Corner

Tags: macos, display

I have a new Macbook Pro 2020 model, have attached a couple of external monitors. Everything was fine until last night, suddenly there is now a semi-transparent white box appearing on the top left corner of only the external monitors, not my actual laptop screen.

I've rebooted, looked at what loads up on login...

Screenshot attached. [image: Annoying Box]

Can't figure it out, does anyone have any ideas on how to get rid of the annoying white menace?

Comment: Can you confirm you’re using the latest OS (just a troubleshooting step)? Are you able to test other MacBooks/computers with those monitors?

Comment: This also can manifest in the same top left corner of the screen as a blur / frosted glass effect. Excellent reporting and image to explain this glitch.

Comment: I just got another monitor (Philips 32in 4k) today, this just happened today after switching to RTS mode (in the monitor itself's menu settings). I have two 4k monitors connected to Macbook pro 16in (12.4 MacOS), only the Philips with RTS mode has this issue, but not the other mode or the second monitor.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same problem with my MacBook Pro M1 Max 2021. It just happened out of the blue while connecting the laptop to my docking station.

I **solved** the problem by **switching** the display modes on my 4k monitors in the settings (of the monitor itself - **not** in macOS).

- Previously it was in RTS Mode (I guess for gaming) and then I just switched to another mode/profile.
- When I switch back to RTS, the translucent box returns again.

It is very weird, hope this helps someone else with the issue.